# body: padding-top: 60px + height 100% = strange results

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed header with `height: 60px; left`, top & left `0`

Therefore my body gets `padding-top: 60px`

Now look what happens...

the padding-top of body is exactly half the height of the header.
[image: body padding-top 60px]

[image: well, one is lying oO]

It is just crazy...
Well, one of them is lying.., right?

I get in all sorts of trouble with padding-top on the body all the time.
What is happening here?

### WHAT I TRIED

`position: static` doesn't change a thing.

### META:

The issue occurs in latest Safari, Chrome & Firefox on
MacBook Pro Retina 15'' late 2013 running OS X 10.11.6

Comment: Just to point out for CSS correctness, you should be using `margin` instead of padding. `padding` is for internally styling an element, `margin` for externally, which is what you're doing here. Just some food for thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem while writing this post;
still wanted to share it and maybe get some opinions.

I had `height: 100%` on the `<body>` (and `<html>`)
That resulted in this behavior.

I'd still like to know why the hell it was "perfect half" and why it happened in the first place.

Please don't ask me why I had `height:100%` set to begin with; .. it had a reason in previous projects, but I can't remember it.